# Email photos in full resolution from iPhone 6 running iOS 8

Tags: email, photos, ios

iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1.3. How do I email photos with full resolution. I go to Photos, select some photos, pick Mail, then compose the email. No where in "New Message" does it give me an option to pick the resolution. Once I press send the email is sent with the photos at 1280x960.

**Follow-up** - For some reason the photo was less than 500KB thus the email app didn't offer an option to resize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOS 8.x does not prompt for resolution options when using the front facing camera, only the rear facing camera.  The front facing camera will usually max out resolution with a file size in KB.

Answer (score 1):

Once you hit 'Send' you should then get an option sheet to decide what size…

[image]

Try rebooting the phone.

If no joy, then try
Sync; backup; restore.